# Trait 'App/Elasticquent Trait ' not found laravel5.2 and elasticsearch-2.3.2

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

I want to use elastic search.I install elastic search-2.3.2 .and add this package to require in composer.json

```
"fairholm/elasticquent": "1.0.*",
```

And this my Product model

```
    <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;


class Product extends BaseModel
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable =array('name','id','title','description','image','price','category_id','brand_id','created_at_ip','updated_at_ip');

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'name' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
        'description' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            "analyzer" => "stop",
            "stopwords" => [","]
        ],
    );

}
```

I get  two error

```
Undefined namespace Elasticquent
Undefined class ElasticquentTrait
```

How to fix it?
Please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following at the top of your file:

```
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;
```

Otherwise class autoloader is looking for the trait in current namespace.

Comment: I already add use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait; But get error  undefined namespace Elasticquent  how to fix it?